# How to serve static HTML files with vanilla javascript including submodules?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack

I want to serve a static html file with elements defined in a javascript file using imports from submodules. How is this possible with vanilla JS? Or do I need some bundling tools and / or other frameworks? Example code structure to illustrate my intention:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <div id="screen">
    <div id="grid"></div>
  </div>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import { buildGrid } from "./buildGrid.js"
var http = require("http");
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
      }
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.header("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
      res.end(data);
    });
  })
  .listen(8080);

buildGrid();
```

**buildGrid.js**

```
export function buildGrid() {
    let grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.className = "cell";
    cell.textContent = "test;
    grid.appendChild(cell);
}
```

**style.css**

```
body,
html {
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}
#screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #2d2f34;
}
```

Comment: Your `index.js` file contains JavaScript that should be on the server, not on the client. You can bundle all your client JS files to a single file with a bundler, but you don't have to. It's perfectly fine to `import` from another JS file. Have you checked out the extensive [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) on this subject?

Comment: Ok, but when I import the ```buildGame()``` ,  it will contain browser specific elements that should be on the client? Like 
```let grid = document.getElementById("grid"); ```

Comment: Yeah, that part is in the right place and should stay on the client.

Comment: @CaminoDS You are mixing client and server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the code to a server part and a client part solved my issues, as correctly pointed out in the comments.

So all the server handling was placed in a `server.js` file, while the client specific content (which is to be injected into the `index.html`  file) was placed in the `index.js` file.

Furthermore, I also utilized submodules to separate different parts of the `index.js` file. So it was need to specify `<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>` on the import in the `index.html`file. And in the `server.js` file, the different file types were handled by setting the header based on the file type in the request.
Hope the following will be of help for others serving HTML with JS modules using nodejs.

So the end file structure was like this

- `server.js`
- `index.js`
- `buildGrid.mjs`
- `style.css`
- `index.html`

**server.js**

```
"use strict";
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

function readFile(req, res) {
  var filePath = __dirname + req.url;

  fs.readFile(filePath, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write("Not found error 404");
      res.end();
    } else {
      const url = req.url === "/" ? "/index.html" : req.url;
      if (req.url.includes("js"))
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
      if (req.url.includes("css")) res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/css");
      if (req.url.includes("html")) res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    }
  });
}

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    readFile(req, res);
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <div id="screen">
    <div id="grid"></div>
  </div>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import { buildGrid } from "./buildGrid.mjs"
export function main {
 buildGrid()
}
```

**buildGrid.mjs**

```
export function buildGrid() {
    let grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.className = "cell";
    cell.textContent = "test;
    grid.appendChild(cell);
}
```

**style.css**

```
body,
html {
  background: #111;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```